# Downloading a auto generated pdf file from controller in mvc3 using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having a problem regarding downloading auto generated pdf file from controller.

I had created a pdf file and i wants it to download through browser.

My code is as follows-

```
 [pdf.IAMEViewPdf(this, null, "Voluntaryletter_pdf", Equiplist);]
```

here m generating a pdf, now I want to download it in the browser.

Thanks..

Comment: What is `pdf` ? What system/tool are you using to generate the PDF ?

Comment: We need more detail on that attribute. A snippet of the response output would be helpful as well. ADDITIONALLY, you need to define "problem" in much much much more detail than just "I have a problem".

Comment: Dear Hardrada,
Here I am using itextsharp dll to generate PDF file.

I succeed to generate PDF File but failed to download the same file through browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307143/itextsharp-mvc-view-to-pdf

Answer (score 1):

When you have dynamically generated your PDF file, you probably have it in a byte array. Then just write (in the MVC controller):

```
byte[] pdfFile = ...;
return File(buffer, "application/pdf", "Voluntaryletter.pdf");
```